# Rails 3.1 - timestamps in model and delayed time

Tags: time, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, timestamp, datecreated

I have generated a model in my Rails app (3.1) and I have a problem about saving the time into  the DB table (through timestamps). The time is delayed of one hour. Exist any global solution of set up the time for timestamps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the timestamps will always be saved in the database in UTC format. It's when you display them that they should be translated in the desired timezone.

To change the default timezone of your app: `config.time_zone = "UTC"`.
You can find all timezones here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: I tried to set in `application.rb` timezone for my country, but unfortunately without success, stil the same. When I print the time from database, the output is `2011-12-02 23:55:25 +0100` I tried to convert it, like `my_time = current_user.created_at   my_time.in_time_zone("Prague")`, but I still haven't the output `00:55:25` (still is there only **+0100**)

Comment: So, the solution is `@data. created_at.localtime`